# Code not creating access token when authenticating account for Google API

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

When I run my code, I am able to login, but as soon as I try to authenticate, the server crashes and I'm assuming that's because I am not getting any access tokens. I am not sure on where to go next. I have downloaded the .json file for my credentials and its called 'credentials.json'

This is my Google.py

```
import pickle
import os
import datetime
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes, prefix=''):
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    
    cred = None
    working_dir = os.getcwd()
    token_dir = 'token files'
    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}{prefix}.pickle'

    ### Check if token dir exists first, if not, create the folder
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir))

    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file)):
        with open(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file), 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file), 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(f'Failed to create service instance for {API_SERVICE_NAME}')
        os.remove(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file))
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    API_NAME = 'calendar'
    API_VERSION = 'v3'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    CLIENT_FILE = 'client-secret.json'
    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES, 'x')
```

This is my code to run

```
from pprint import pprint
from Google import Create_Service

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json'
API_NAME = 'calendar'
API_VERSION = "v3"
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
```

Comment: How are you connecting to your server? You need to be on the machine to be able to open the pop-up window for authentication.

Comment: It opens up safari for me to login to my gmail account and I am using Visual Studio Code

Comment: @MattNguyen I test your code and is working for me. Could you share a screenshot with what you call "server crash"? The console is returning any error?

Comment: It just opens up a page that says it failed to load, I don't get back any authorization tokens